# Swift: How to pass data from selected cell using Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to pass data from selected cell to ViewController.
With my code just pass data from the last cell no matter which cell is selected.

' func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return guestsList.count
}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestCell", for: indexPath) as! GuestTableViewCell
    let guest: GuestModel
    guest = guestsList[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.guestNameLabel.text = guest.guestName
    cell.attendingLabel.text = guest.attendingStatus
    cell.menuLabel.text = guest.menuStatus
    cell.ageLabel.text = guest.ageStatus
    cell.tableLabel.text = guest.tableNo
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toGuestDetails", sender: self
    )

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toGuestDetails"{
        if let indexPath = guestsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! GuestDetailsViewController
            destinationVC.guestDetail = [guestsList[indexPath.row]]
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let guest = guestsList[indexPath.row]
        self.guestsList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.guestsTableView.reloadData()
        self.deleteGuest(id: guest.id!)
    }
}

func deleteGuest(id: String){
    refGuests.child(id).setValue(nil)
    self.guestsTableView.reloadData()
}'
```

And here is my ViewController with details:

'   @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var emailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var phoneNoLabel: UILabel!

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var guestDetail = [GuestModel]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   
    showGuestDetails()
   
}

func showGuestDetails(){
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!).child("guests")
    ref.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            self.guestDetail.removeAll()
            
            for guests in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                let guestObject = guests.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let guestName = guestObject?["guestName"]
                let guestFamilyName = guestObject?["guestFamilyName"]
                let phone = guestObject?["guestPhoneNumber"]
                let email = guestObject?["guestEmail"]
              
                
                let guestDetails = GuestModel(guestName: guestName as? String, guestFamilyName: (guestFamilyName as? String)!, guestPhoneNumber: phone as? String, guestEmail: email as? String)
                
                let fullName = guestDetails.guestName! + " " + guestDetails.guestFamilyName!
                
                self.nameLabel.text = fullName
                self.emailLabel.text = guestDetails.guestEmail
                self.phoneNoLabel.text = guestDetails.guestPhoneNumber
                self.guestDetail.append(guestDetails)

            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure when you select a cell it becomes selected?

Comment: @Aznix how to check that? When I click on any cell, it opens view controller with detalis, but just with data from last cell.

Comment: You can add variable `var lastSelectedIndexPath: IndexPath?` and `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toGuestDetails", sender: self)
}`
And in `prepare(for segue` use `lastSelectedIndexPath`

Comment: @Aznix doesn't work. It's same data from the last cell, no matter which cell I clicked.

Comment: Add `print(indexPath)` at `didSelectRowAt` function to see is click work correctly.

Comment: @Aznix I printed and it works, but data transfer doesn't seem to work still.